# display image that stored in database asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, sql-server-2008

This is my database:

```
 create table images 
(
 ID int primary key identity, 
 Name nvarchar(255),
 Size int, 
 ImgData varbinary(max) 
)

CREATE PROCEDURE UploadImages
 @Name nvarchar(255),
 @Size int,
 @ImgData varbinary(max),
 @NewId int output
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO images
     VALUES (@Name, @Size, @ImgData)

SELECT @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()    
END

Create procedure spGetImageById 
@ID int
as
Begin
Select ImgData
from images where ID=@ID
End
```

This is my code in admin page That i write to save images in database and hyperlink appear to can see the image in another page to make sure it is correct image:

```
HttpPostedFile PostedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;

string fileName = Path.GetFileName(PostedFile.FileName);
string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
int fileSize = PostedFile.ContentLength;

if(fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".bmp"|| fileExtension.ToLower() == ".gif" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
 {
  Stream stream = PostedFile.InputStream;
  BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);

  byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

  string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UploadImages", con);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       con.Open();

     SqlParameter paramName = new SqlParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "@Name",
         Value = fileName
     };
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramName);

     SqlParameter paramSize = new SqlParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "@Size",
         Value = fileSize
     };
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSize);

     SqlParameter paramImgData = new SqlParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "@ImgData",
         Value = bytes
     };
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramImgData);

     SqlParameter paramNewId = new SqlParameter()
     {
         ParameterName = "@NewId",
         Value =-1,
         Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
     };
     cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNewId);

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();

     Lmas.Visible = true;
     Lmas.Text = "done";
     Lmas.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
     HyperLink1.Visible = true;
     HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "~/ShowImage.aspx?Id=" + cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value.ToString();
    } 
} 
  else 
  {
    Lmas.Visible = true;
    Lmas.Text = "only images (.jpg .png .gif .bmp) can be uploaded";
    Lmas.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
     HyperLink1.Visible = false;
   }
```

I write this to make kind of review to the imges :

```
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageById", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter paramID = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@ID",
            Value = Request.QueryString["ID"]
        };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
        }
```

I want to display the image in my main page in img-tag.
So i tried to copy the code that make you review the image into my main page but it says:"Procedure or function 'spGetImageById' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied".

Comment: are you sure it's a png?

Comment: yes,i am sure. And when i make it jpg and upload jpg file not work too

Comment: This code work only when it display into ShowImage.aspx to can display it .
but when i try to use it to dispaly image in img-tag or label it does not work

Comment: use lower case data:image/png also, might not make a difference. but try it.

Comment: Could be the context of the code, like does it run in `IsPostback`? Use the debugger to capture the result of your data uri and paste it into a simple html file with an `img` tag. Open in a browser and see if it works. That narrows down where the problem is.

Comment: Why use a data URL? Why not have separate image handler responsible for retrieving the image that you can create a URL to?

Comment: How large is the image?

Comment: 20kB only all the images not large

Comment: have you tried a break point at `string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);` to make sure that `bytes` has data?

Comment: Yup,That code is work.
I want code make the image display in another the main page in img-tag

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to get the all of the bytes, try replacing

```
string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

with

```
string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Also change to lowercase on the word Image:

Image1.ImageUrl = "data:**image**/png;base64," + strBase64;

Comment: can you paste the base64 string here? I want to see if it looks like a base64 string.

Comment: I try to dispaly image in main page so copy the code to my main page and it says :" Procedure or function 'spGetImageById' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied."

Comment: Sounds like you are not passing on the query string the ID, besure when you call your main page: http://whatever/your_main_page.aspx?ID=1234

Comment: The same. nothing change

Comment: can you right click on the page (view source) and paset what the image tag looks like?

Comment: <img data-u="image" id="img" runat="server" alt=""  />